# Problems with testing in app purchases

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am trying to test my application with in app purchases. I created features, test user, logged out from iTunes on the iPhone and used developer certificate. Load app from XCode in debug mode.

When I click "Buy" button I pass all checks for internet availability, canMakePayments and call

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:featureId];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

But all what I see is a pending view and after some minutes it failed in

```
- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{   
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)      
    {       
        NSLog(@"failedTransaction");
    }   
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] paymentCanceled];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]; 
}
```

Please advice in what direction I should go to figure out the problem and what else I should check.

*P.S. All related questions on SO were checked with no luck.*

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some ideas:

1. Load the products before allowing the user to make purchases. The first thing you need to do is a SKProductsRequest and make sure the products you are offering can be purchased.
2. Discriminate the error, Check SKError.h to see the different kinds of
   errors the store can return. This way you will have a clearer idea of what's going on
3. Some errors, like -1003, are not documented and they seem to be
   weird cases in the sandbox environment.
4. For those errors, make sure you:

   - Use the correct test user.
   - Have properly configured the products in iTunes connect.
   - Logout from the store and clean install the app. Login only when you are asked to do so in the buy confirmation popup.
   - If this fails, reset the network settings, clean install the app and test again.
   - If this fails, reset all settings, clean install the app and test again.
   - If this fails, reset your device, clean install the app and test again.

Finally, take a look at these pages:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/